# Exchange 2010, sharing calendars and reviewer permissions

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, exchange, exchange-2010

For shared calendars, when I set the "reviewer permission" to a user, Outlook shows an error message saying "It is impossible to see and update the calendar".

It looks like the "reviewer permission" doesn't allow the associated permissions to the user.

Configuration :

- O.S : Windows Server 2008 R2
- Exchange version : 2010 SP3 Rollup 17

Does anyone has had this problem, and knows how to resolve this ?
Thank you for any intervention